# Map with custom key in Scala

Tags: scala

There is a string representation of some data:

```
"jsonData": {
      "data1": {
        "field1": "data1",
        "field2": 1.0,
        "field3": true
      },
      "data211": {
        "field1": "data211",
        "field2": 4343.0,
        "field3": false
      },
      "data344": {
        "field1": "data344",
        "field2": 436778.51,
        "field3": true
      },
      "data41": {
        "field1": "data41",
        "field2": 14348.0,
        "field3": true
      }
    }
```

How do I represent it in Scala? I thought I could be either

```
Map[(String, Double, Boolean), String]
```

or

```
type KeyValueType = (String, Double, Boolean)
Map[KeyValueType, String]
```

But nevertheless, it gave me the errro:

```
error: missing arguments for method apply in class GenMapFactory;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

and also, I'm unsure it if would be the right representation.

So how do I represent it and, if my approach is right, how do I get rid of the error?

Comment: Isn't `(String, Double, Boolean)` rather the value type and `String` the key?

Comment: well, you have a key, say "data1" which has three value fields of type `(String, Double, Boolean)` or even `(Double, Boolean)` since the first element seems to be (always?) the same. Thus, `Map[String, (Double, Boolean)]` looks more appropriate to me, unless you really want to specify "data1" by the three values. However, since both versions are unique in the example, only you can really tell :).

Comment: Off topic, but in case someone lands here because of a search on the error message,  `val map : Map[KeyValueType, String] = Map[KeyValueType, String]` should be `val map : Map[KeyValueType, String] = new Map[KeyValueType, String]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your error, you probably just need to add `()` to invoke the `apply` method, since just an object name (`Map`) with type parameters is meaningless.

I would advise against using tuples to hold your data. They are over-used by beginners. Use a class instead. Something like

```
case class MyDataType(field1: String, field2: Double, field3: Boolean)
```

Then you read you data into a `Vector[MyDataType]`.

Comment: 1) Why Vector? I need Map. 2) "just need to add () to invoke the apply method" - how do I do this?

Comment: 1) If each "data1" etc is associated with a single instance of your data type then it might make sense to include it as a String field in that data type. But from your example it seems you already have this item duplicated in the first field. If you really need a Map, use a Map. 2) `Map[KeyValueType, String]` is meaningless: use `Map[KeyValueType, String]()`. Although this is not very useful because by default you're using an immutable map.

Comment: why did you suggest to use `case` class, why not just class?

Comment: Case classes are the idiomatic way of representing algebraic data types in Scala. They give you a bunch of things for free like sensible `equals` and `copy` methods but this is well documented elsewhere.

Comment: and one more thing: is my Scala's data type represented properly? I'm confusing keys and values in Map in this particular case.

Comment: In a Map, the key is the first type parameter, and the value is the second.

Comment: I know that, I'am asking if  `Map[KeyValueType, String]` represents my data structure properly, that's why I said -- "in this particular case".