# How to have (Array[Int](9), Int) as key for Map?

Tags: scala

How to have a (ArrayInt, Int) as key for Map?
I basically want an Integer array of size 9 and an Integer as a key for the Map.

I tried something like :

```
scala>   var A:Map[(Array[Int](9), Int),Int] = Map()
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '(' found.
         var A:Map[(Array[Int](9), Int),Int] = Map()
                              ^
```

I looked at a couple other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959263/map-with-custom-key-in-scala), but couldn't really get it!

Or How would I go about using a class instead of a tuple. Is that possible in Scala. I saw some posts using case class, but I thinks thats like an enum thing.

PS: Started with Scala today!

Comment: I'm not sure if you can specify the dimensions, given that you're only declaring the *type* of the key; you're not declaring any implementation specific details.

Comment: christopher is right, you can specify an `Array[Int]` as a key, but you cannot specify the size it should be

Comment: Oh, so I can assign any size to it as I add data later on?

Comment: yes, but if you want to restrict size why don't you just write some function that will do the check prior to adding such element?

Comment: Cool that you can do this in scala but it's a quite smelly key...

Comment: haha.. it's kind of a specification thing!!

Comment: If you want to limit the size you could possibly use a Tuple9[Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int], also expressible as (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int). Not sure what you are doing is a very good idea though.

Comment: @johanandren then you would have to use placeholders for less-than-9 sizes

Comment: ah, sorry didn't see that was a requirement

Comment: Note that Scala uses Java arrays, and so equality is by reference. I.e. if you have two different arrays containing the same data, and one of them is used as part of a key, you can't use the other to retrieve the value. If this is a problem, you should use an immutable sequence (e.g. `List` or `Vector`) instead as the type of the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(K, V)` is a syntaxic sugar for `Tuple2[K, V]`, that is a type constructor. So, `K` must be a type.

In other words, `Array[Int]` is a type.

`Array[Int](9)` is not a type, it's a method call on the companion object, which returns an `Array` of `Int`s that contains one element : 9.